How to make Youtube in Chrome play sound to the laptop's internal loudspeaker?
Windows 10  Youtube in Chrome does not want to play the  video's sound   to the laptop's loudspeaker. In System Settings I try changing  the default sound output. When I change it to  a wireless headset, it does play to my wireless headset, but when I change it to the laptop's internal loudspeaker, no sound.   There is nothing inserted in the laptop's  round headset socket. When the option for  the system  sound output is set to the loudspeaker, when I change the volume, I do hear a ding of varying  voluume in the loudspeaker.

Can other applications play sound on the speakers?

@NickSlash  Yes, Youtube in Firefox does play to the loudspeaker when I set  the loudspeaker as the output device in System  Settings, so probably the problem is specific to Chrome.

Does chrome always fail to play to play sound? Or just this session?

Might be worth trying this?
https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/419128

Finally figured it out! In case anyone else has/had a similar problem,
this is what I did.

Open the Control Panel → Sound → Speakers → Advanced

Un-check "Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device"

Open Volume Mixer

Unmute Chrome

Voila!



